# Возможно ли осуществить раздачу  интернета с помощью wi-fi адаптера asus n-10 в Xubuntu 12.04?

Tags: wifi, xubuntu, linux

Хочу приобрести wi-fi адаптер асус н-10 вот такой: [Wireless-N150 PCI Express Adapter](http://www.asus.com/Networks/Wireless_Adapters/PCEN10/). Если верить описанию на оф.сайте, то под виндой легко реализовать программную точку доступа. Но у меня ПК с убунту на борту, хочу через него раздавать интернет по квартире.

Вопрос: реально ли это сделать и как? Рассмотрю все варианты.

Answer (score 1):

Первая ссылка в гугле - [HowTo: WiFi Access Point средствами Ubuntu](http://skai-falkorr.blogspot.com/2011/10/howto-wifi-access-point-ubuntu.html).

Comment: по вашей ссылке создается режим ad-hoc а не access point

Answer (score 1):

Конечно можно. Это делается утилитами hostapd, dnsmasq и wpa_supplicant. Раньше это делалось с помощью wireless_tools, но он умеет делать только без шифрования.